# Graphviz warning with libgvplugin_pango.so.6 - dot fails to produce PDF

Tags: ubuntu, graphviz, miniconda

For some time now I've not been able to run `dot` commands and now I finally want to fix the problem. The error I get is the following:

```
Warning: Could not load "/usr/bin/miniconda3/lib/graphviz/libgvplugin_pango.so.6" - It was found, so perhaps one of its dependents was not.  Try ldd.
Format: "pdf" not recognized. Use one of: canon cmap cmapx cmapx_np dot dot_json eps fig gv imap imap_np ismap json json0 mp pdf pic plain plain-ext png pov ps ps2 svg svgz tk vdx vml vmlz xdot xdot1.2 xdot1.4 xdot_json
```

When I run `ldd /usr/bin/miniconda3/lib/graphviz/libgvplugin_pango.so.6` I get the following output:

```
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd17995000)
        libgvc.so.6 => /usr/bin/miniconda3/lib/graphviz/../libgvc.so.6 (0x00007fdcc2d2c000)
        libltdl.so.7 => /usr/bin/miniconda3/lib/graphviz/../libltdl.so.7 (0x00007fdcc2d21000)
        libxdot.so.4 => /usr/bin/miniconda3/lib/graphviz/../libxdot.so.4 (0x00007fdcc2d1a000)
        libcgraph.so.6 => /usr/bin/miniconda3/lib/graphviz/../libcgraph.so.6 (0x00007fdcc2cff000)
        libcdt.so.5 => /usr/bin/miniconda3/lib/graphviz/../libcdt.so.5 (0x00007fdcc2cf6000)
        libpathplan.so.4 => /usr/bin/miniconda3/lib/graphviz/../libpathplan.so.4 (0x00007fdcc2ceb000)
        libexpat.so.1 => /usr/bin/miniconda3/lib/graphviz/../libexpat.so.1 (0x00007fdcc2cb6000)
        libz.so.1 => /usr/bin/miniconda3/lib/graphviz/../libz.so.1 (0x00007fdcc2c9c000)
        libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 => /usr/bin/miniconda3/lib/graphviz/../libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 (0x00007fdcc2c8c000)
        libcairo.so.2 => /usr/bin/miniconda3/lib/graphviz/../libcairo.so.2 (0x00007fdcc2aad000)
        libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 => /usr/bin/miniconda3/lib/graphviz/../libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 (0x00007fdcc2c72000)
        libpango-1.0.so.0 => /usr/bin/miniconda3/lib/graphviz/../libpango-1.0.so.0 (0x00007fdcc2c28000)
        libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/bin/miniconda3/lib/graphviz/../libfontconfig.so.1 (0x00007fdcc2be0000)
        libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/bin/miniconda3/lib/graphviz/../libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fdcc2a54000)
        libglib-2.0.so.0 => /usr/bin/miniconda3/lib/graphviz/../libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fdcc2931000)
        libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007fdcc266b000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fdcc2362000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fdcc1f98000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fdcc1d94000)
        libfribidi.so.0 => /usr/bin/miniconda3/lib/graphviz/.././libfribidi.so.0 (0x00007fdcc1d74000)
        libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /usr/bin/miniconda3/lib/graphviz/.././libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fdcc1d6f000)
        libharfbuzz.so.0 => /usr/bin/miniconda3/lib/graphviz/.././libharfbuzz.so.0 (0x00007fdcc1c6f000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fdcc1a52000)
        libpixman-1.so.0 => /usr/bin/miniconda3/lib/graphviz/.././libpixman-1.so.0 (0x00007fdcc1999000)
        libpng16.so.16 => /usr/bin/miniconda3/lib/graphviz/.././libpng16.so.16 (0x00007fdcc1960000)
        libxcb-shm.so.0 => /usr/bin/miniconda3/lib/graphviz/.././libxcb-shm.so.0 (0x00007fdcc195b000)
        libxcb.so.1 => /usr/bin/miniconda3/lib/graphviz/.././libxcb.so.1 (0x00007fdcc192e000)
        libxcb-render.so.0 => /usr/bin/miniconda3/lib/graphviz/.././libxcb-render.so.0 (0x00007fdcc191e000)
        libXrender.so.1 => /usr/bin/miniconda3/lib/graphviz/.././libXrender.so.1 (0x00007fdcc1911000)
        libX11.so.6 => /usr/bin/miniconda3/lib/graphviz/.././libX11.so.6 (0x00007fdcc17cd000)
        libXext.so.6 => /usr/bin/miniconda3/lib/graphviz/.././libXext.so.6 (0x00007fdcc17b8000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fdcc15b0000)
        libxml2.so.2 => /usr/bin/miniconda3/lib/graphviz/.././libxml2.so.2 (0x00007fdcc1447000)
        libuuid.so.1 => /usr/bin/miniconda3/lib/graphviz/.././libuuid.so.1 (0x00007fdcc143e000)
        libffi.so.6 => /usr/bin/miniconda3/lib/graphviz/.././libffi.so.6 (0x00007fdcc1433000)
        libpcre.so.1 => /usr/bin/miniconda3/lib/graphviz/.././libpcre.so.1 (0x00007fdcc13eb000)
        libiconv.so.2 => /usr/bin/miniconda3/lib/graphviz/.././libiconv.so.2 (0x00007fdcc1303000)
        libpng12.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0 (0x00007fdcc10dd000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fdcc2bb6000)
        libgraphite2.so.3 => /usr/bin/miniconda3/lib/graphviz/../././libgraphite2.so.3 (0x00007fdcc10af000)
        libXau.so.6 => /usr/bin/miniconda3/lib/graphviz/../././libXau.so.6 (0x00007fdcc10a9000)
        libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/bin/miniconda3/lib/graphviz/../././libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007fdcc10a1000)
        libicuuc.so.64 => /usr/bin/miniconda3/lib/graphviz/../././libicuuc.so.64 (0x00007fdcc0ec9000)
        liblzma.so.5 => /usr/bin/miniconda3/lib/graphviz/../././liblzma.so.5 (0x00007fdcc0ea0000)
        libicudata.so.64 => /usr/bin/miniconda3/lib/graphviz/.././././libicudata.so.64 (0x00007fdcbf45b000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/bin/miniconda3/lib/graphviz/.././././libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fdcbf2e7000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/bin/miniconda3/lib/graphviz/.././././libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fdcbf2d3000)
```

I never used `ldd` before, but if I understand this correctly, nothing is actually missing? I have no idea what I can do to make this work again, and since I'm working on a server shared with my colleagues, I also don't know what "broke" graphviz for me.

I would be grateful for any suggestions to get rid of this error.

Comment: Same problem here, not a single clue what caused this. I was using jupyter notebook and `graph-tool` to plot some network, and suddenly the whole conda environment kinda breaks down. The kernel dies every time i trynna plot something, and neither did `conda update` or `conda install` works without reporting package conflicts once. Even creating a new conda env didn't work...

Comment: Ah, damn, I was hoping I could set up a new environment later... I hope someone figures this out.

Comment: Try `conda install -c conda-forge graphviz=2.46.1 python-graphviz`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what fixed it for me:

`sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y libxau6`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on a Mac. I use a Conda environment for my work

```
conda install -c conda-forge xorg-libxrender xorg-libxpm
```